# Short cut key for jumping to end of the macro block in eclipse kepler

Tags: eclipse, macros, key, shortcut, eclipse-kepler

What is the short cut key for "jump to end of the macro block" in eclipse

For example, if there is a block like this

```
#ifdef MACRO_NAME
......
.....
#endif
```

How could I jump from `#ifdef` line to the `#endif` line using shortcut keys?

Comment: Perhaps you should state your question, otherwise is difficult to guess what you need to know

Answer (score 0):

Use Ctrl+Shift+P to goto matching bracket.

if ()
{ //from here

### --

--

} // to here